# Does difficulty of task increase perceived authority?

Tags: social-psychology, terminology

I'm writing a research paper and I'm wondering if someone can help me out by throwing out a few terms. I'm looking for a theory that talks about how the more difficult a task is, the more authoritative / appreciated is the person who completed the task.

For example, let's say Exam A is only passed by 5% of people that take it. Is there a cognitive theory that says that people who pass the exam will be more appreciated / seen as more authoritative given that they completed a task most fail at?

Comment: Authoritative on what subject though? :) Knowledge does not transfer between domains that easily. Are you interested in 'general knowledge' of some sorts?